# Cómo validar que el usuario me entre solo letras

Tags: c

¿Cómo puedo validar una cadena de caracteres que me entre el usuario,en la cual, solo pueden haber letras? 
En C

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes. Te recomiendo que antes de nada pases por el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour).Pulsa en [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/223646/edit) y añade información de lo que pretendes y sobre todo lo que has intentado y qué problemas concretos has tenido. Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para más información en cómo mejorar la pregunta. Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se en que lenguaje estas trabajando pero aun asi podrias intentar validar la cadena por el codigo ASCII aqui te dejo un ejemplo:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cadena.length(); i++) {

if (cadena.chartAt(i)-'0' >= 65 && cadena.chartAt(i)-'0' <= 90 || cadena.chartAt(i)-'0' >= 97 && cadena.chartAt(i)-'0' <= 122){
   return true;
} 
else
return false;
```

Espero te sirva de algo.

Comment: El lenguaje en el que estoy trabajando es en C